# Can't get JSON object from a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, json

In my directive I am calling a function that's returning me the content of a JSON file, the content looks like this:

```
{
    "UpdatedBy" : "Naguib",
    "UpdatedOn" : "29/09/2016",
    "UpdatedFrom": "data.doc",
    "100":
    [
        {
            "title":"Class View",
            "overview":"TBC",
            "menuItem":"TBC",
            "UpdatedBy" : "Naguib",
            "UpdatedOn" : "29/09/2016"
        }
    ],
    "101":
    [
        {
            "title":"Time Table",
            "overview":"TBC",
            "menuItem":"TBC",
            "UpdatedBy" : "Naguib",
            "UpdatedOn" : "29/09/2016"
        }
    ]
}
```

The function is working fine and returning me a JSON array in `$scope.helptext`
So when I call `helptext` from HTML and pass the index of the first dimention it returns an array with the data but I can't get any data in the nested array:

```
 <pre>
        ONE
        {{helptext[101]}}
        TWO
        {{helptext[101].menuItem}}
        THREE
        {{helptext[101][menuItem]}}
        FOUR
        {{helptext[101]['menuItem']}}
 </pre>
```

returns
[image]

The html that is generated is exactly how it looks:

```
<pre class="ng-binding">                
                ONE
                [{"title":"Time Table","overview":"TBC","menuItem":"TBC","UpdatedBy":"Naguib","UpdatedOn":"29/09/2016"}]
                TWO

                THREE

                FOUR

</pre>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196) ... the output of your object clearly shows that the values of `helptext[100]` and `helptext[101]` are **arrays**. Arrays don't have a `menuItem` property. The objects *contained* in these arrays do. This has nothing to do with Angular, only with how you structure your data and how to access objects/arrays.

Comment: You're right @FelixKling I removed the Angular JS tag and any references to it from my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access each of them like an array: `{{helptext[101][0].menuItem}}`

If you need to display each possible `menuItem` nested within those `100`, `101`, etc. arrays, look into using [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Something like this should help get you started:

```
<pre ng-repeat="menuData in helptext[101]">{{menuData.menuItem}}<pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that the following worked:

`{{helptext[101][0].menuItem}}`

`{{helptext[101][0]['menuItem']}}`

Answer (score 1):

Can  you try TWO

```
{{helptext[101][0].menuItem}}
```